# JavaScript: How to clear my custom keyboard mappings and use the default ones

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, web-applications

In my web application I define my own keyboard event handler and override some default key mappings:

```
document.onkeydown = function(eventParam)
    {
        var keycode;
        keycode = eventParam.which;

        // detect ESC key
        if (keycode == 27)
        {
            //close the window
            LightboxFileInfo.close();
        }

        return true;
    };
```

However, at another point in my web application, i want to clear my custom key mappings and to use again the default ones. This is my problem. Could you please advise how to do just that? How to clear all my keyboard mappings and again to use the default ones without restarting the web-application?

Basically, my web application has numerous windows. The windows are lightboxes. For each window/lightbox I use different functions for the same keys. Remember, that I have a web application, not a website. It means, that everything occurs in one webpage/JavaScript Document, where I display different windows through the already mentioned lightboxes and not as different .html/.php files.

If I need to save the default keyboard mappings before changing them, then fine. Would you please advise how to do that? My JavaScript knowledge simply ends here. Of course, I look for the simplest solution.

I am looking for a solution using:

- **JavaScript**

I do not use jQuery, just plain JavaScript.

Besides that, I use:

- HTML 5
- CSS 3
- PHP 5.5.8
- MySQL 5.6.15
- Apache 2.4.7

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't disabling the default behavior with `eventParam.preventDefault();`, the normal defaults should work too in the first place. But to disable your own functionality from being called, you can just override the handler function with empty one

```
document.onkeydown = function() { };
```

Comment: hi and thank you very much for this answer. In other words, if I define my own handler function does not yet mean, that I am disabling the default ones. Great answer, thank you. +1. What you please have advice what to do, when I have `eventParam.preventDefault();` defined. I have this function defined in some places on my code. I do not yet know, if they can affect the keyboard mappings too.

Comment: Lets clarify what the default means: For example, if you have form and you hit `Enter`, the default behavior is to submit the form. If you though bind your own handler for key presses, and call `e.preventDefault()`, the the form isn't submitted. This preventing can of course be done per key code to for example prevent default behavior only for backspace. But the default will never again be prevented, if you remove the whole handler like I suggested on my answer so you are good to go then again with the default behavior not prevented.

Comment: perfect and clear answer. Thank you very much. I do not have any other questions regarding this subject and I am therefore marking this answer as the *Accepted Answer*. Have a nice day. +1